# "TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array" when attempting to read a .mat file using scipy.io.loadmat

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I have such a code:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import shlex
import os
import numpy as np
import scipy.io

script_dirname = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


def get_windows(image_fnames, cmd='selective_search'):
    f, output_filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.mat')
    os.close(f)
    fnames_cell = '{' + ','.join("'{}'".format(x) for x in image_fnames) + '}'
    command = "{}({}, '{}')".format(cmd, fnames_cell, output_filename)
    print(command)

    mc = "matlab -nojvm -r \"try; {}; catch; exit; end; exit\"".format(command)
    pid = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(mc), stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), cwd=script_dirname)
    retcode = pid.wait()
    if retcode != 0:
        raise Exception("Matlab script did not exit successfully!")

    all_boxes = list(scipy.io.loadmat(output_filename)['all_boxes'][0])
    subtractor = np.array((1, 1, 0, 0))[np.newaxis, :]
    all_boxes = [boxes - subtractor for boxes in all_boxes]

    os.remove(output_filename)
    if len(all_boxes) != len(image_fnames):
        raise Exception("Something went wrong computing the windows!")
    return all_boxes

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import time

    image_filenames = [
        script_dirname + '/000015.jpg',
        script_dirname + '/cat.jpg'
    ] * 4
    t = time.time()
    boxes = get_windows(image_filenames)
    print(boxes[:2])
    print("Processed {} images in {:.3f} s".format(
        len(image_filenames), time.time() - t))
```

The code is tested, and it has to work.

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "selective_search.py", line 62, in <module>
    boxes = get_windows(image_filenames)

  File "selective_search.py", line 42, in get_windows
    all_boxes = list(scipy.io.loadmat(output_filename)['all_boxes'][0])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 131, in loadmat
    MR = mat_reader_factory(file_name, appendmat, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/mio.py", line 55, in mat_reader_factory
    mjv, mnv = get_matfile_version(byte_stream)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py", line 218, in get_matfile_version
    buffer = fileobj.read(4))

TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

I'm using MATLAB 2015.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess where the TypeError occured?

Comment: `TypeError` looks like a `python/numpy` error, not something the MATLAB code produced.  Besides giveing error callback stack, you need to give some of the printout (with added diagnositic prints if needed).  Help us pinpoint the source of the error.

Comment: Actually the same code used to work in a different computer successfully. I swear I didn't change the code.

Comment: Thanks to the new stack information, I've deduced that the MATLAB script did not run, or at least did not overwrite the temp file that this script created at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I told you, I have run the code in different computer which has MATLAB 2014, and it worked.

In that computer, gcc version was 4.7, but in the current computer which has MATLAB 2015, gcc version is 4.9.

I have removed gcc 4.9, and installed 4.7, and the problem has been solved. :)

Answer (score 4):

This script constructs a command line, calls MATLAB with that, and then reads the `.mat` produced.

I think you need to test the pieces:

- does the MATLAB calling command look right?
- does the MATLAB run fine?
- is the .mat valid (read with MATLAB)?
- can you read it from Python - just a plain `loadmat`?

How long ago was it when it ran?  For what MATLAB version?  You may need to change this script so it does not destroy the temporary file, giving you a chance to test it interactively.

One possibility is that the .mat is in a format that `loadmat` can't handle.  MATLAB keeps changing the .mat format, the latest being some form of `hd5?`.  You might need to change the MATLAB script so it uses an earlier format.  I don't recall what kind error `loadmat` produces when loading a newer incompatible version.

---

The `TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array` error is something I'd expect from a `np.ndarray()` call, not the usual `np.array`.  But digging into the `loadmat` code, `scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py` I see that it does use `ndarray`.  That does point to some sort of file format incompatibility, either the MATLAB file version, or maybe a 32/64 bit machine difference.

---

The error is in the

```
def get_matfile_version(fileobj):
```

function, right at the start where it tries to read the 1st 4 bytes of the file:

```
# Mat4 files have a zero somewhere in first 4 bytes
fileobj.seek(0)
mopt_bytes = np.ndarray(shape=(4,),
                       dtype=np.uint8,
                       buffer = fileobj.read(4))
```

It's reading the bytes, and trying to create an array directly from them.  That looks like a straight forward operation.  Except, what would happen if the file was empty?  The buffer would be 0 bytes, too small.  If so, then the problem is the MATLAB failed to run or to save its file.  I'll have to experiment.

---

BINGO - the .mat file is empty

```
In [270]: with open('test.mat','w') as f:pass  # empty file
In [271]: matlab.loadmat('test.mat')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/io/matlab/miobase.py in get_matfile_version(fileobj)
    216     mopt_bytes = np.ndarray(shape=(4,),
    217                            dtype=np.uint8,
--> 218                            buffer = fileobj.read(4))
    219     if 0 in mopt_bytes:
    220         fileobj.seek(0)

TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

So for some reason, the MATLAB script failed.  `mkstemp` creates an empty temporary file.  Normally the MATLAB script would over write it (or append?).  But if the script fails (to run), then this file remains empty, producing this error when you try to read it.

If you used `tempfile` to get a file name, rather than create the file, you'd get an `OSError`, 'no such file'.

I don't think the `scipy` developers anticipated someone would try to load an empty .mat file, otherwise they would have caught and translated this error.

Comment: I have run it last week in different computer. The MATLAB version was 2014a.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but did submit a close vote - because of incomplete information regarding the error.

Comment: Okay, I'm editing the question. Could you please explain me the solution more briefly?

Comment: By the way hpaulj, I have changed narray as ndarray, it didn't work.

Comment: Where did you change 'ndarray` (or v.v)?  `np.array` and `np.ndarray` are used in different ways.

Comment: here: subtractor = np.darray((1, 1, 0, 0))[np.newaxis, :] in this code

Comment: When I pinpointed `ndarray` as the problem, I did not mean for you to change the script.  The problem is in `loadmat`, and actually the result of an earlier MATLAB failure.

Comment: So, hpaulj, what do you suggest me to do?

Comment: I would change how `outfilename` is created (and # the remove), and then figure out whether the MATLAB command created the file, and where it put it.  This is an OS level problem that we can't solve remotely.